# bad argument #1 to 'narrow' (number expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, torch

I'm trying to implement this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06962.pdf with lua/torch7
During the forward pass I got no problem but for the backward pass `modele.gapbranch:backward(n, loss_grad)` I got this error :

> ```
> /home/narimene/distro/install/bin/luajit:
> ...e/narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:67:  In 2 module of nn.Sequential:
> /home/narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Concat.lua:92: bad argument #1 to 'narrow' (number expected, got nil)
> stack traceback:
>   [C]: in function 'narrow'
>   /home/narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Concat.lua:92: in function </home/narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Concat.lua:47>
>   [C]: in function 'xpcall'
>   ...e/narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:63: in function 'rethrowErrors'
>   .../narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:84: in function 'backward'
>   gap2.lua:240: in function 'opfunc'
>   /home/narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/sgd.lua:44: in function 'sgd'
>   gap2.lua:247: in main chunk
>   [C]: in function 'dofile'
>   ...ene/distro/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
>   [C]: at 0x563fabe66570
>
> WARNING: If you see a stack trace below, it doesn't point to the place
> where this error occurred. Please use only the one above.
> stack traceback:
>   [C]: in function 'error'
>   ...e/narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:67: in function 'rethrowErrors'
>   .../narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:84: in function 'backward'
>   gap2.lua:240: in function 'opfunc'
>   /home/narimene/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/sgd.lua:44: in function 'sgd'
>   gap2.lua:247: in main chunk
>   [C]: in function 'dofile'
>   ...ene/distro/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
>   [C]: at 0x563fabe66570
> ```

Here is the code (gap2.lua):

```
require 'nn'
require 'cunn'
require 'cutorch'
local GapBranch, Parent = torch.class('nn.GapBranch', 'nn.Module')

function GapBranch:__init(label, num_classes, args, threshold)
    Parent.__init(self)
    self.gt_labels = label 
    num_classes = num_classes ~= nil and num_classes or 10
    self.threshold = threshold or 0.6


    self.gapbranch = nn.Sequential()
    self.gapbranch:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3,512, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1)) -- cette ligne est a enlever

    self.cls = self:classifier(512, num_classes)
    self.cls_erase = self:classifier(512, num_classes)
    self.gapbranch:add(nn.Concat():add(self.cls):add(self.cls_erase))
    --self.gapbranch:add(self.cls_erase)

    --Optimizer
    self.loss_cross_entropy = nn.CrossEntropyCriterion():cuda()

end


function GapBranch:classifier(in_planes, out_planes)
    gapcnn = nn.Sequential()
    gapcnn:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(in_planes, 1024, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
    gapcnn:add(nn.ReLU())
    gapcnn:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1024, 1024, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
    gapcnn:add(nn.ReLU())
    gapcnn:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1024,out_planes, 1, 1, 1,1))

    return gapcnn

end


function mulTensor(tensor1, tensor2)

    newTensor = torch.Tensor(tensor1:size()):cuda()
    for i=1, tensor1:size()[1] do
        for j=1, tensor1:size()[2] do 
            newTensor[{i,j}] = torch.cmul(tensor1[{i,j}],tensor2[{i,1}])
        end
    end

    return newTensor
end


function GapBranch:erase_feature_maps(atten_map_normed, feature_maps, threshold)

    if #atten_map_normed:size()>3 then  
        atten_map_normed = torch.squeeze(atten_map_normed)
    end

    atten_shape = atten_map_normed:size()
    pos = torch.ge(atten_map_normed, threshold)
    mask = torch.ones(atten_shape):cuda() -- cuda   
    mask[pos] = 0.0

    m = nn.Unsqueeze(2)
    m = m:cuda()
    mask = m:forward(mask) 
    erased_feature_maps = mulTensor(feature_maps,mask) -- Variable 

    return erased_feature_maps

end


function GapBranch:normalize_atten_maps(atten_map)
    atten_shape = atten_map:size()
    batch_mins, _ = torch.min(atten_map:view(atten_shape[1],-1),2)
    batch_maxs, _ = torch.max(atten_map:view(atten_shape[1],-1),2)

    atten_normed = torch.cdiv(atten_map:view(atten_shape[1],-1)-batch_mins:expandAs(atten_map:view(atten_shape[1],-1)), (batch_maxs - batch_mins):expandAs(atten_map:view(atten_shape[1],-1)))
    atten_normed = atten_normed:view(atten_shape)

    return atten_normed
end


function GapBranch:get_atten_map(feature_maps, gt_labels, normalize) 
    normalize = normalize or true
    label = gt_labels:long()

    feature_map_size = feature_maps:size()
    batch_size = feature_map_size[1]
    atten_map = torch.zeros(feature_map_size[1], feature_map_size[3], feature_map_size[4])


    atten_map = atten_map:cuda()
    for batch_idx = 1, batch_size do  
        -- label.data[batch_idx]
        --label[batch_idx]
        print('label ',label:size())
        print('feature_maps ', feature_maps:size())
        atten_map[{batch_idx}] =  torch.squeeze(feature_maps[{batch_idx,label[batch_idx]}])
    end 

    if normalize then
        atten_map = self:normalize_atten_maps(atten_map)
    end

    return atten_map
end 

function GapBranch:gaplayer()
    gaplayer = nn.Sequential()
    gaplayer:add(nn.SpatialZeroPadding(1, 1, 1 ,1))
    gaplayer:add(nn.SpatialAveragePooling(3, 3, 1, 1))

    return gaplayer 
end
function GapBranch:updateOutput(input) -- need label 

    -- Backbone
    feat = self.gapbranch:get(1):forward(input)

    self.gap = self:gaplayer()
    self.gap:cuda()
    feat3 = self.gap:forward(feat)

    m = nn.Unsqueeze(2)
    m = m:cuda()
    -- Branch A

    out = self.gapbranch:get(2):get(1):forward(feat3)
    self.map1 = out
    logits_1 = torch.squeeze(torch.mean(torch.mean(out, 3), 4))

    logits_1 = m:forward(logits_1)
    print('logits_1 ',logits_1:size())

    --feat5 = self.gapbranch:get(2):get(2):forward(feat3)


    localization_map_normed = self:get_atten_map(out, self.gt_labels, true)     
    self.attention = localization_map_normed  
    feat_erase = self:erase_feature_maps(localization_map_normed, feat3, self.threshold)

    -- Branch B
    out_erase = self.gapbranch:get(2):get(2):forward(feat_erase)
    self.map_erase = out_erase

    logits_ers = torch.squeeze(torch.mean(torch.mean(out_erase, 3), 4))

    m = nn.Unsqueeze(2)
    m = m:cuda()
    logits_ers = m:forward(logits_ers)
    print('logits_ers ', logits_ers:size())
    return {logits_1, logits_ers}
end

function GapBranch:get_loss(resModele, gt_labels)

--[[    if self.onehot == 'True' then
        gt = gt_labels:float()
    else
        gt = gt_labels:long()
    end
--]]
    print('resModele ', resModele[1])
    loss_cls = self.loss_cross_entropy:forward(resModele[1], gt_labels)
    loss_cls_ers = self.loss_cross_entropy:forward(resModele[2], gt_labels)
    loss_val = loss_cls + loss_cls_ers

   return {loss_val, }
end

require 'paths'
if (not paths.filep("cifar10torchsmall.zip")) then
    os.execute('wget -c https://s3.amazonaws.com/torch7/data/cifar10torchsmall.zip')
    os.execute('unzip cifar10torchsmall.zip')
end
trainset = torch.load('cifar10-train.t7')
testset = torch.load('cifar10-test.t7')
classes = {'airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck'}


-- ignore setmetatable for now, it is a feature beyond the scope of this tutorial. It sets the index operator.
setmetatable(trainset, 
    {__index = function(t, i) 
                    return {t.data[i], t.label[i]} 
                end}
);
trainset.data = trainset.data:double() -- convert the data from a ByteTensor to a DoubleTensor.

function trainset:size() 
    return self.data:size(1) 
end

mean = {} -- store the mean, to normalize the test set in the future
stdv  = {} -- store the standard-deviation for the future
for i=1,3 do -- over each image channel
    mean[i] = trainset.data[{ {}, {i}, {}, {}  }]:mean() -- mean estimation
    print('Channel ' .. i .. ', Mean: ' .. mean[i])
    trainset.data[{ {}, {i}, {}, {}  }]:add(-mean[i]) -- mean subtraction

    stdv[i] = trainset.data[{ {}, {i}, {}, {}  }]:std() -- std estimation
    print('Channel ' .. i .. ', Standard Deviation: ' .. stdv[i])
    trainset.data[{ {}, {i}, {}, {}  }]:div(stdv[i]) -- std scaling
end

trainset.data = trainset.data:cuda()
trainset.label = trainset.label:cuda()
modele = nn.GapBranch(trainset.label):cuda()
modele.gapbranch = modele.gapbranch:cuda()


print(modele.gapbranch)
theta, gradTheta = modele.gapbranch:getParameters()

optimState = {learningRate = 0.15}

require 'optim'

for epoch = 1, 1 do
    function feval(theta)

        for i=1, 1 do 
            modele.gapbranch:zeroGradParameters()
            m = nn.Unsqueeze(1)
            m = m:cuda()
            n = m:forward(trainset.data[i])
            h = modele:forward(n)

            j = modele:get_loss(h,trainset.label[i])
            loss_cls_grad = modele.loss_cross_entropy:backward(h[1],trainset.label[i])
            loss_cls_ers_grad = modele.loss_cross_entropy:backward(h[2],trainset.label[i])
            loss_grad = loss_cls_grad + loss_cls_ers_grad

            loss_grad = torch.randn(1,10,32,32):cuda()


            modele.gapbranch:backward(n, loss_grad)

        end     
        return j, gradTheta

    end
    print('***************************')
    optim.sgd(feval, theta, optimState)
end
```

If anyone could help i would be very grateful

Comment: Are you sure that's the right code? I can't find `gapbranch:backward` anywhere. I also cannot find `narrow` anywhere.

Comment: you have it in the end of the code modele.gapbranch:backward(n, loss_grad) and narrow i couldn't find it also

Comment: can I have your email I fixed this problem but still have some problems and questions about lua/torch

Comment: I don't know anything about torch, I'm afraid - I was simply looking for errors you might've overlooked.

Comment: I changed nn.concat() to concatTable() in init method but got another wiered error and i dont know how to fix it :(